# Property 'delegate' not found on object of type

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uistoryboardsegue

Anyone can encountered this?
Basically I have created `UITableViewController` in Dynamics Protocols,
Wondering why I can't set `UIStoryboard Segue`

> Error, "Property 'delegate' not found on object of type
>   'SettingTableViewController'

I want to have each assign screen.

Here is the source code,

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Don't post screenshot of code, post code directly instead!

Answer (score 0):

As you set the tableview's dataSource with code, but why not set the delegate?
I think you shoud add the code after setting dataSource:

```
self.settingTableView.delegate = self;
```

Comment: I did. But unused variable 'ifvc' :)

Comment: where you declared the delegate property and what you want to do with that ?. Post .h code also

Answer (score 0):

If want to set current `viewcontroller` as a delegate of any `viewcontroller` then you require to confirm protocol for that. For example if your viewcontroller have tableview and you are using tableview's `datasource and delegate` methods then you require to confirm `UITableViewDelegate` and `UITableViewDataSource` protocol something like,

```
@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>
```

Here you're error says that you can't set `pvc or cpvc or buvc` as  a delegate of current viewcontroller. Now why ? there are many factor can affect that!

refer [this tutorial](http://iosdevelopertips.com/objective-c/the-basics-of-protocols-and-delegates.html) for more about protocol and delegates!

Answer (score 0):

Change your segue method with these line may be that would be work :

```
    settingTableViewViewController * Vc = (settingTableViewViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
self.delegate = vc ;
```

manage according to your view controller.

Comment: read the image carefully , a custom delegate passing is happening between Tableview and destanation view

Comment: change initialisation directly like this :

Comment: settingTableViewViewController * Vc = (settingTableViewViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
self.delegate = vc ;